# In AngularJS v1.4.8 pass Anonymous function as a parameter to function in ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to store a call to an anonymous function via ng-init.
ie

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="AVF"  ng-controller="ConfigController"    ng-init="RegisterInitFunction(function() { $scope.GetData(); })" >
```

In my controller

```
   $scope.InitFunction = null;
   $scope.RegisterInitFunction = function(init) {
     $scope.InitFunction=new Function(init)();

    }
    $scope.GetData = function() {
      $scope.DoSomething();
    }
```

I end up getting a syntax error 
angular.min.js:107 Error: [$parse:syntax]

Is this possible ?

Comment: Angular is giving you your answer. It does not support that syntax. Hard to tell from here what part of the syntax it doesn't like, though.

Answer (score 0):

Fyi to anyone who might have this issue putting the anonymous function in quotes and using eval like so solved my dilemma,

... ng-init="RegisterInitFunction('function() { $scope.GetData(); }');"

```
        $scope.InitFunction = null;
    $scope.RegisterInitFunction = function(init) {
        $scope.InitFunction = eval('(' + init + ')');
    }
```